# How to batch convert actionscript2 .fla files to actionscript3

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, batch-file, actionscript-2

I have a lot of fla files that developed in actionscript-2 (about 2 thousands) and I now want to convert them to actionscript-3. Is there any way to do this? Should I do this with macro in adobe flash? Or use programming languages such as C# to extract the actionscript files from fla files and convert them then recompile with new actionscripts? If yes, then please guide me how.

Comment: Find a unicorn, ride it to the end of the nearest rainbow, and use the script inside the pot of gold.    Seriously though, your question is much too broad for StackOverlow, there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: This will be very difficult to do in an automated fashion unless there is a very specific, predictable pattern your 2 thousand files.   If that is the case, then you could write a script to parse your 2000 files and convert the necessary deficiencies.

Comment: @LDMS Thank you. Yes there is predictable pattern for files. I can categorize them base on their pattern. I have three to four pattern in actionscripts.

Comment: You should modify your question and carefully describe the three or four cases of required modifications, including an example of input and output that have all the cases. Read [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6108)

Comment: there's no way to auto convert as2 to as3. It has to be done manually.

Comment: @BotMaster OK, thanks. So is there any way to extract actionscript codes from fla files in c#? Then I would converting as2 scripts to as3. I think that this is routine and there is an algorithm to convert my scripts, because they have 3 to 4 predictable pattern.